# Random lines drawn on screen while all vertexes are correct

Tags: opengl, c++, 2d, lines

I'm writing a 2D program in which a monocycle follows a Catmull-Rom spline. My problem is when I write the circle, the drawing goes crazy. There is one line on the screenshot (which seems to be 3 when watching it), that rotates with the circle and blinks around it.

[image: Screenshot showing errant red line]

It doesn't happen always, comes randomly, sometimes it's fine then it will start this after a few seconds.

I have no clue what could cause it. My calculations are correct, there aren't fauly or nans/inf-s in the array, and if I put `printf` right before buffering the vbo, the lines don't appear, so I can't even debug it. And sometimes there's a small blinking in the green part too.

Here's some part of my code.

Creating the curve:

```
void Create() {
    // Curve
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoCurve);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoCurve);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vboCurve); // Generate 1 vertex buffer object
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboCurve);
    // Enable the vertex attribute arrays
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);  // attribute array 0
    // Map attribute array 0 to the vertex data of the interleaved vbo
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), NULL); // attribute array, components/attribute, component type, normalize?, stride, offset
}

void Create() {
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoCyclist);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoCyclist);
    // Curve
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboCyclist); // Generate 1 vertex buffer object
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboCyclist);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboHuman); // Generate 1 vertex buffer object
    // Enable the vertex attribute arrays
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);  // attribute array 0
    // Map attribute array 0 to the vertex data of the interleaved vbo
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2*sizeof(float), NULL); // attribute array, components/attribute, component type, normalize?, stride, offset
}
```

Calculating:

```
humanData.clear();
        circleData.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < 180; i++) {
            cordX = cosf((float)M_PI * i * 2 / 180.0f);
            cordY = sinf((float)M_PI * i * 2 / 180.0f);

            if (i == 0) {
                circleData.push_back(cordX);
                circleData.push_back(cordY);
            }

            else if (i == 179)
            {
                circleData.push_back(cosf((float)M_PI * i * 2 / 180.0f));
                circleData.push_back(sinf((float)M_PI * i * 2 / 180.0f));

                circleData.push_back(cosf((float)M_PI * i * 2 / 180.0f));
                circleData.push_back(sinf((float)M_PI * i * 2 / 180.0f));

                circleData.push_back(cosf((float)M_PI * 0 * 2 / 180.0f));
                circleData.push_back(sinf((float)M_PI * 0 * 2 / 180.0f));
            }

            else {
                circleData.push_back(cordX);
                circleData.push_back(cordY);
                circleData.push_back(cordX);
                circleData.push_back(cordY);
            }
        }
```

Draw:

```
mat4 MVPTransform = MrotateTranslate() * camera.V() * camera.P();

MVPTransform.SetUniform(gpuProgram.getId(), "MVP");

int colorLocation = glGetUniformLocation(gpuProgram.getId(), "color");

for (int i = 0; i < circleData.size() - 1; i++)
    printf("%f\n", circleData[i]);

glBindVertexArray(vaoCyclist);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboCyclist);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, circleData.size()* sizeof(float), &circleData[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
if (colorLocation >= 0) glUniform4f(colorLocation, 0.72f, 0.16f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, circleData.size());
```

Cyclist attributes:

```
class Cyclist {
private:
    unsigned int vaoCyclist, vboCyclist;
    unsigned int vboHuman;
    float r= 1;
    float v = 0;
    vec2 wTranslate = vec2(-10.0f, 0.0f);
    vec2 position = vec2(0, 0);
    float sina, fi=0, ds;
    float cordX, cordY;
    vector<float> circleData;
    vector<float> humanData;
    float dir = 1.0f;
```

Comment: Why does your `for` loop  in the Draw section skip the last element? Is `circleData.size()` what you think it should be?